# Stock Game Ranking System

Tags: ranking

I'm currently making a stock game where the user can buy fictional stocks. Upon registering the user will receive 1.000.000 DKK (danish krone) to spend on stocks.

I'm trying to create a ranking system, but I found this to be more difficult than I had imagined.

By giving the user 1.000.000 at the start of the game it's hard to evaluate how good a player is doing when compared to an inactive player.

Thing is, a player could sign up and receive the money and then do nothing else and (probably) do better than a lot of the people who get negative. In this way, inactive players are rewarded for doing nothing and will look better on the scoreboard.

Is there a good way to avoid this?

Comment: What about to send (DKK storage+ (DKK earned+ DKK invested)? That will solve all

Answer (score 1):

Rank players only by the amount that they receive after investing the money.

That way you rank they by their profit score.

Comment: What about a user who only goes in minus (unlikely, but could happen), should he be at the same point as inactive players? or should the ranked list exclude players who haven't made a single purchase (thus marking them unranked)?

Comment: It's up to you.. I'd rank the players that buyed stuff based on how much do those stocks currently worth. And if you use this method inactive players would have zero score.

Answer (score 1):

I would rank people by their net worth, starting credits and all. If the value of the player's stocks have gone down, so be it. It's still useful to know if you're doing better than players that have just started.